# In Clojure, how can I terminate this loop properly

Tags: loops, clojure

I am just getting in to Clojure and wanted to do some simple functions to get my feet wet and try and get away from my Imperative programming background.

This below simply searches a string for repeating elements, however the loop seems to spin it out of control; what have I done wrong? And yes, this probably looks imperative; I'm still trying to wrap my head around functional programming and non-state changes. And yes the html is not validated, I'm simply using it as an example.

```
(def src "
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Astronomy
  </title>
  <title>Science
  </title>
  </head>
  </html>
")


(defn findit [ele body i]
  (let [n (.indexOf body (clojure.string/join ["<" ele ">"]) i)]
    (if (> n -1)
      (let [n2 (.indexOf body (clojure.string/join ["</" ele ">"]) (+ n 1))] ;if we found opening element, then find closing element
        (if (> n2 -1) ;found both open and close of element?
          [(subs body (+ n (.length ele) 2) n2) (+ n2 1)]))))
  )

; (let [[r i] (findit "title" src 69)] (println i) (if r (println r,i)))

(defn findthem [ele body]
  (loop [x 0]
    (let [[r i] (findit ele body 0)]
      (println r,i)
      (if i
        (recur i)))
    )
  )

(findthem "title" src)
```

Comment: It may help for you to try this: (loop [x 0] (println "hello") (let [i 42] (if i (recur i))))

Comment: that would result in an infinite loop, correct? wouldn't it be (recur (- i 1)) or something similar to help it decrement and stop looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `let` statement, which occurs every iteration of the loop, `findit` is called with the index as `0`, not `x` (or, `i`).

```
(defn findthem [ele body]
  (loop [i 0]
    (let [[r i] (findit ele body i)]
      (println r i)
      (when i
        (recur i)))))
```

Comment: thank you, I see what I did wrong here; erasing and rewriting code and I forgot to put that together! what is the benefit of using when versus if?

Comment: @scape: When you have code for only true condition then use `when` else use `if`.. just to make it more readable

Comment: @scape Plus, `when` contains an implicit `do` (i.e., its body can contain any number of statements), so if, for example, you only wanted to print when `i` was not `nil`, you could write `(when i (println r i) (recur i))`